# Cannot deploy HelloWorld contract to my netowrk (testrpc)

Tags: solidity, contract-development, truffle

**ANSWER TO THIS QUESTION IS HERE :** https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48044742/cannot-deploy-helloworld-contract-to-my-network-testrpc

pardon my basic question, bud what else do i need to deploy my contract?

I have **simple Hello World  contract** defined as follows
HelloWorld.sol:

```
pragma solidity ^0.4.17;

contract HelloWorld{  
    function sayHello() internal pure returns(string){
        return("Hello 2018!");
    }
}
```

Initial migrations.js:

```
var Migrations = artifacts.require("./Migrations.sol");
var HelloWorld = artifacts.require("./HelloWorld.sol");

module.exports = function(deployer) {
  deployer.deploy(Migrations);
  deployer.deploy(HelloWorld);
};
```

And finally since im using truffle, truffle.js:

```
module.exports = {

  networks: {
    development: {
      host: "localhost",
      port: 8545,
      network_id: "*" // Match any network id
    }
  }

};
```

When I run commands:

```
truffle compile
truffle migrate
```

Then go to console:

```
   truffle console
```

and i use js:

```
var hw
HelloWorld.deployed().then(function(deployed){hw=deployed;});
```

I get

> Error: HelloWorld has not been deployed to detected network
>   (network/artifact mismatch)
>       at C:\Users\Kofola\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\truffle\build\cli.bundled.js:317116:17
>       at 
>       at process._tickDomainCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:228:7)

**How do i correctly deploy my contract and test its method?**

I should also add that my testrpc server is running at 8545 and everything seems to be alright. (all of this is running on localhost) I have tried to specify id of the network, i explicitly set id and specified it in truffle.js, still not working. I also tried to change visibility of the function.

Comment: Your _truffle.js_ says "8545"; your comment at the end says "8548". Is it as simple as that?

Comment: @benjaminion Sorry , typo when typing question on my part. Its 8545. Problem still persist

Comment: I am running the same issue. Any luck with the Answer?

Comment: This does not really answer the question. If you have a different question, you can ask it by clicking [Ask Question](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/ask). You can also [add a bounty](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/set-bounties) to draw more attention to this question once you have enough [reputation](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/help/whats-reputation). - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/20237)

Answer (score 1):

Run this on truffle console:

```
var hw = HelloWorld.at(HelloWorld.address);
```

Check the address:

```
hw.address
```

call your function:

```
hw.sayHello();
```

Comment: Hello ,  please move to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48044742/cannot-deploy-helloworld-contract-to-my-network-testrpc There is more up to date information about the question. I will post my result of your  commands into  SO question.